# Como sumar los últimos 2 dígitos de un número en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, lista, arraylist, sum

Quiero hacer un programa que sume los dos últimos dígitos de un número entero positivo sin importar que tan grande sea, como por ejemplo 4153, siendo la respuesta 8, ó 523, siendo la respuesta 5.

Por ahora he hecho esto:

```
numero = 1233 // Por ejemplo

console.log(numero.toString().split('').reduce(function(a, b) { return a - a + parseInt(b) }, 0));
// El resultado es 3
```

Lo que hice fue convertirlos en string en una lista, luego dígito por dígito sumarlo, con la única diferencia que el mismo número es eliminado por él mismo hasta llegar hasta el último (si le quitara el -a lo que haría el programa es sumar todos los dígitos que tiene el número).

Lo que necesito es cómo modificar ese código de tal forma de que sólo se sumen los 2 últimos dígitos.

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar tomando las ultimas posiciones de la cadena. Por ejemplo.

```js
let number = 33123;
let strNumber = number.toString();

let sum = parseInt(strNumber[strNumber.length - 2]) + parseInt(strNumber[strNumber.length - 1]);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Y cómo hago para volverlo como una función? porque cuando intento modificarlo como una función me retorna "undefined".
`function sum(number) {
  parseInt(number.toString()[number.toString().length - 2]) + parseInt(number.toString()[number.toString().length - 1]);
}
`

`console.log(sum(25146));`

Comment: Te falta poner un `return` antes del primer `parseInt(blablabla)`. Si no indicas qué debe devolver la función, no devuelve nada! Quedaría así: `function sum(number) {   return parseInt(number.toString()[number.toString().length - 2]) + parseInt(number.toString()[number.toString().length - 1]); }`

Comment: Muchas gracias, en verdad es de mucha ayuda <3

Answer (score 5):

En mi opinión es mejor omitir el tratamiento con strings. Se puede hacer simplemente con operaciones matemáticas usando el operador `%`:

```js
function suma2(numero){
    return (numero%10) + ((numero%100)-(numero%10))/10;
};

console.log(suma2(4146));
console.log(suma2(213));
console.log(suma2(15887));
console.log(suma2(33123));

// También funciona aunque el número solo tenga 1 dígito
console.log(suma2(5));
```

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta!

Answer (score 4):

Con [`slice(-2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice) extraes los 2 últimos caracteres y, dentro de `reduce()`, conviertes cada caracter a entero:

```js
function sumaUltimos2(num) {
    if(!parseInt(num)) {
        return 0;
    }
    let str = num.toString().slice(-2);
    return str.split('').reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b));
}

console.log(sumaUltimos2(4146));
console.log(sumaUltimos2(213));
console.log(sumaUltimos2(15887));
// Funciona aunque el número solo tenga 1 dígito
console.log(sumaUltimos2(5));
console.log(sumaUltimos2());
console.log(sumaUltimos2('ABCD'));
```

Comment: Bonito oneliner te ha quedado!. Supongo que el `parseInt()` de un null es 0? O qué valor tiene b si solo pasas un número?

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, modifiqué la respuesta para devolver cero en caso de errores. En cuanto al `parseInt()` cuando solo hay un número, `reduce()` asigna al primer parámetro (`a`) un valor inicial en caso de que no lo especifiques y, por lo visto, no es _null_

Comment: Curioso. Hace un par de días descubrí el método `reduce()` y todavía estoy jugando con él un poco. Excelente respuesta, @Triby!

Comment: @Benito-B, según el manual de MDN, [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) nombra el primer argumento _"acumulador"_ y, a menos que envíes un parámetro con valor inicial, entiendo que comenzará en cero. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo matemáticamente extrayendo los valores.

```js
var number = 1234
var sum = number%10 + Math.floor(number/10)%10;
console.log(sum);
```

Ejemplo creando una función:

```js
function sumaUltimosDigitos(numero,digitos){
  if (isNaN(digitos)) digitos = 2; // Por defecto suma los 2 ultimos.
  else digitos=Math.floor(digitos); // Se assegura que sean enteros.
  if (isNaN(numero)) throw "sumaUltimosDigitos() requiere paràmetro númerico";
  
  var suma=0;
  for (let i=0; i<digitos; i++){
    suma+=Math.floor(numero/Math.pow(10,i))%10;
  }
  return suma;
}
console.log(sumaUltimosDigitos(123456));
```